SAS: How to use do-loop within a macro to transpose data?
For a school assignment I am required to use a do-loop within a macro in SAS to transpose data. Currently each year is a separate variable along the top of my dataset. I need the year to be a single variable going down on the left side of my dataset.
%macro school_transpose;
  array enroll{13} Total_Enroll_2017-Total_Enroll_2005;
  %do i=6 %to 18;
  data school_enroll_transpose;
    set school_enroll;
    year=2004+i;
    total_enroll=enroll{i};
  run;
%end;
%mend;
%school_transpose;


Get a refund from the instructor!

https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/sas/modules/how-to-reshape-data-wide-to-long-using-proc-transpose/

https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/sas/modules/reshaping-data-wide-to-long-using-a-data-step/

Did they explain why they wanted it embedded in a macro?  What is expected to change between different calls to the macro?  What parameters will the macro take?

Did they ask you to use a DO loop (part of the DATA step) or a %DO loop (part of the macro language)?

Realistically, you should use Proc TRANSPOSE.
The SET statement helps define the program data vector (PDV), so if you want a new variable in the left most position you will want to specify it with a statement such as length or attrib before the SET statement.
The macro shown is not useful because the output data set is replacing the same named one created by earlier iterations of your macro loop.
An array based tranposition would use a DATA step DO loop, and that could be inside a macro.  Is the assignment to use a macro %DO loop?
Your array statement is OUTSIDE the DATA step and that is wrong.
Example:
DO loop inside a macro.  The year is part of the metadata (i.e. part of the variable name) and extracted from the variable name while iterating over the data step variable based array.
Really is no-need for this processing to be in a macro.
%macro ...

  data want (keep=year total_enroll);
    set have ;
    array enroll Total_Enroll_2017-Total_Enroll_2005 ; 
    do idx = 1 to dim(enroll) ;
      name = vname(enroll[idx]) ;
      year = input (scan(name,-1,'_'),??best.) ;
      total_enroll = enroll[idx] ;
      if not missing(year) then output ;
    end ;
  end ;

%mend ;



Same as Richard's answer with test data and implicit subscripting.  I like PROC TRANSPOSE as there are many other useful features. This example only scratched the surface of TRANSPOSE features.
/* Test data wide format */
data have;
   length school 8;
   array enrol Total_Enroll_2017-Total_Enroll_2005;
   do school = 1 to 10;                            
      do over enrol;
         enrol = int(1e2*ranuni(9));;
         end;
      output;
      end;
   run;
proc print heading=vertical;
   run;

data flip(keep=school year Total_enroll);
   set have;
   array enrol Total_:;
   do over enrol;
      year = input(scan(vname(enrol),-1,'_'),10.);
      Total_Enroll = enrol;
      output;
      end;
   run;
proc print data=flip(obs=15);
   run;

/* my preference is to use TRANSPOSE*/
proc transpose data=have out=flip2(rename=(Col1=Total_Enroll));
   by school;
   var Total_:;
   run;
data flip2;
   set flip2;
   year = input(scan(_name_,-1,'_'),10.);
   drop _name_;
   run;
proc print data=flip2(obs=15);
   run;


No idea how using a macro would help as you can already do this with either PROC TRANSPOSE or a DATA step.
But let's play along.  The purpose of a macro is to generate SAS code.  So first let's create some SAS code.  Once we have some working code we can then explore how to make that code using the macro language.
So one way to convert a single observation into many is to execute multiple OUTPUT statements.  So you might do something like:
data school_enroll_transpose;
    set school_enroll;
    year=2005;
    total_enroll=total_enroll_2005;
    output;
    year=2006;
    total_enroll=total_enroll_2006;
    output;
    ...
    year=2017;
    total_enroll=total_enroll_2017;
    output;
    drop total_enroll_2005-total_enroll_2017;
run;

So to generate that with a macro you would need two inputs. The start year and the end year.
%macro school_transpose(from_yr,to_yr);
%local yr;
data school_enroll_transpose;
    set school_enroll;
%do yr=&from_yr %to &to_yr;
    year=&yr;
    total_enroll=total_enroll_&yr;
    output;
%end;
    drop total_enroll_&from_yr-total_enroll_&to_yr;
run;
%mend school_transpose;

Which you could then call like this:
%school_transpose(from_yr=2005,to_yr=2017)

